# React confirm email with request from API

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm stuck with a problem.
Any user that create an account get an email (sent from backend) with a link confirmation.
When the user click that link, it send a request type:

```
{
  "confirm_link": "/auth/confirm/id/emailtype/****token****"
}
```

My problem is: How do I check in my front if the user has clicked so I can be able to display a simple react toast like 'Your account as been verified' ?

Thank you !

Comment: maybe keep a flag in the database whether the user has opened the link or not. It will be set to true/1 only if he opened it up. Which of course you should handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the email confirmation request is completed you can use websockets to send a message from server to client notifying that account is verified.you can display your toast